# Share image via WhatsApp

Tags: swift, share, whatsapp

I have in my app button to share image via whatsapp and it does work. But there is some strange thing appears in the menu of UIDocumentInteractionController on some devices. 
This is the code:

```
        let urlWhats = "whatsapp://app"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: urlString) {

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {

                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.ivFramedPicture.image!, 1.0) {
                    let tempFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("/Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")
                    do {
                        try imageData.write(to: tempFile, options: .atomic)
                        self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: tempFile)
                        self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self
                        self.documentInteractionController.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
                        self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)

                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // Cannot open whatsapp
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
If I click on the 1 whatsapp icon it sends some file that doesn't open on iPhones (Android opens that file like image)

[image]

Does anyone can help to resolve that problem? I want only one icon with share image, that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `UIActivityController` for `sharing` functionality instead of all that code.

**Example:**

```
    if let image = self.ivFramedPicture.image
    {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller)